# How to get VID and PID in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, get, usb, pid

I need to create a program that detect if a certain USB device is plugged. So lets say that we have a device that have `VID (Vendor ID) = 9839` and `PID (Product ID) = 5453`.

I need a code that when i plug the device, the program get automatically the `VID` and the `PID` of the device, and write them in two texboxes.

After that is simple, I use:

```
If textbox1.Text = "9839" And textbox2.Text = "5453" then
   MsgBox("You plugged the device!")
Else
   MsgBox("Device is not plugged")
End If
```

But i need the code for getting `VID` and `PID` of the inserted device into textboxes.
So if someone could help me, let me know :)

I tried a solution using  USBCLASSLibrary Demo 
wich is a free dll but my pc is a x64 one and the dll is x32 so i get a error in C# (Bad Image Format) or something else.

I tried using a code found on CodeProject

```
        private void USBPort_USBDeviceAttached(object sender, 
             USBClass.USBDeviceEventArgs e)
{
   if (!MyUSBDeviceConnected)
   {
      if (USBClass.GetUSBDevice(MyDeviceVID, MyDevicePID, 
                                ref USBDeviceProperties, false))
      {
         //My Device is connected
         MyUSBDeviceConnected = true;
          }
       }
    }

private void USBPort_USBDeviceRemoved(object sender, 
             USBClass.USBDeviceEventArgs e)
{
   if (!USBClass.GetUSBDevice(MyDeviceVID, MyDevicePID, 
                              ref USBDeviceProperties, false))
   {
      //My Device is removed
      MyUSBDeviceConnected = false;``
   }
}
```

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried HIDs?

```
Debug.WriteLine("  HIDD_ATTRIBUTES structure filled without error.")
                            Debug.WriteLine("  Structure size: " & MyHid.DeviceAttributes.Size)
                            Debug.WriteLine("  Vendor ID: " & Hex(MyHid.DeviceAttributes.VendorID))
                            Debug.WriteLine("  Product ID: " & Hex(MyHid.DeviceAttributes.ProductID))
                            Debug.WriteLine("  Version Number: " & Hex(MyHid.DeviceAttributes.VersionNumber))
```

And then, try :

```
 Try
        myVendorID = Int32.Parse(txtVendorID.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        myProductID = Int32.Parse(txtProductID.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score -2):

create combo box named cmbHdd and place the code on your form. this will populate the combo with usb devices and also get ALL required info from Win32_DiskDrive aswell as Win32_USBHub for the PID and Vendor ID
Hope this helps.. 
malvastyle team

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim mosDisks As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive")

    For Each moDisk As ManagementObject In mosDisks.[Get]()
        cmbHdd.Items.Add(moDisk("Model").ToString())
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmbHdd.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim GetQuery As String = ("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" & cmbHdd.SelectedItem & "'")
        Dim mosDisks As New ManagementObjectSearcher(GetQuery)

        For Each moDisk As ManagementObject In mosDisks.[Get]()
            lblType.Text = moDisk("MediaType").ToString().Trim
            lblModel.Text = moDisk("Model").ToString().Trim
            lblSerial.Text = moDisk("SerialNumber").ToString().Trim
            lblInterface.Text = moDisk("InterfaceType").ToString().Trim
            lblCapacity.Text = moDisk("Size").ToString() & " bytes (" & Math.Round((((CDbl(Convert.ToDouble(moDisk("Size"))) / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), 2) & " GB)".Trim
            lblPartitions.Text = moDisk("Partitions").ToString().Trim
            lblSignature.Text = moDisk("Signature").ToString().Trim
            lblFirmware.Text = moDisk("FirmwareRevision").ToString().Trim
            lblSylinders.Text = moDisk("TotalCylinders").ToString().Trim
            lblSectors.Text = moDisk("TotalSectors").ToString().Trim
            lblHeads.Text = moDisk("TotalHeads").ToString().Trim
            lblTracks.Text = moDisk("TotalTracks").ToString().Trim
            lblBytesPerSector.Text = moDisk("BytesPerSector").ToString().Trim
            lblSectorsPerTrack.Text = moDisk("SectorsPerTrack").ToString().Trim
            lblTrackPerCylinder.Text = moDisk("TracksPerCylinder").ToString().Trim
            ' lblProductID.Text = moDisk("PNPDeviceID").ToString().Trim
            lblVendorID.Text = moDisk("PNPDeviceID").ToString().Trim
        Next

        Dim USBClass As New System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub")
        Dim USBCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = USBClass.GetInstances()
        Dim _USB As System.Management.ManagementObject
        Dim _tempID As String = ""

        For Each _USB In USBCollection
            Dim splitString As String() = (_USB("DeviceID")).Split(New [Char]() {"/"c, "\"c, CChar(vbTab)})
            _tempID = splitString(1)
            If (lblVendorID.Text).Contains(splitString(2)) Then
                lblSerial.Text = splitString(2)
                Exit For
            End If
            _tempID = ""
        Next

        If _tempID <> "" Then
            Dim splitID As String() = _tempID.Split(New [Char]() {"&"c, CChar(vbTab)})
            Dim splitVendor As String() = splitID(0).Split(New [Char]() {"_"c, CChar(vbTab)})
            Dim splitProduct As String() = splitID(1).Split(New [Char]() {"_"c, CChar(vbTab)})

            lblVendorID.Text = splitVendor(1)
            lblProductID.Text = splitProduct(1)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```